# Element found on appium studio doesn't work for appium standalone server and vice versa

Tags: java, appium, appium-desktop

The element which I am capturing via desktop inspector not working on appium studio and working fine when I run via appium stand alone server ?

-Is there any reason behind that?

-Any solution if I capture element from anywhere it works irrespective of any server?

-How to write relative xpath of below code ?

```
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[1]
```

I am automating an app using appium, so via desktop inspector I captured some element. and when I ran the code it was working fine.
But for on xpath I used appium studio because in desktop inspector it was an absoulute xpath and it was quite long. but when I executed this script got failed on appium studio however it was working fine on appium standalone server.and same thing happened when I located the element via appium studio and tried to run on appium.

-Captured element cant run on both the server ?

//appium studio

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='action_contacts']")).click();-- 

id -action_contacts
resource id - com.appName.chatapp:id/action_contacts
class - android.widget.FrameLayout
```

//Desktop inspector

```
driver.findElement(By.id("Contacts")).click();

accessibility id    Contacts
id  com.appName.chatapp:id/action_contacts
xpath   //android.widget.FrameLayout[@content-desc="Contacts"]
```

An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The correct locators would be:

1. [ID](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/AppiumDriver.html#findElementById-java.lang.String-): `driver.findElement(By.id("action_contacts")).click();`
2. [XPath](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/AppiumDriver.html#findElementByXPath-java.lang.String-): `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'action_contacts')]")).click();`, you need to use [`contains()` function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) in order to make a match on the partial text.

Comment: and what would be the relative path of this below code?

/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.view.ViewGroup[1]